# Refactoring functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm quite new with JQuery but Google is currently my best friend with constructing the code.  The code below is a little long-winded and I'm wondering if a) I've done it the correct way (it all works fine) and b) is there a better way of doing this?  I'm sure there's simpler methods to achieve what I need to but the code I've put together does what it needs to.  I suppose I'm just asking for critique on what I've learnt.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    window.$order = "GetData.asp";
    GetData();
    window.$ord == '';
    $("#descn").hide();         
    $("#desc").hide();          
    $("#desct").hide();         
});
$("#asc").click(function(){
    window.$order = "GetData.asp?order=asc";
    GetData();
    $("#desc").show();  
    $("#asc").hide();   
});
$("#desc").click(function(){
    window.$order = "GetData.asp?order=desc"
    GetData();
    $("#desc").hide();  
    $("#asc").show();
});
$("#ascn").click(function(){
    window.$order = "GetData.asp?no=asc";
    GetData();
    $("#descn").show(); 
    $("#ascn").hide();  
});
$("#descn").click(function(){
    window.$order = "GetData.asp?no=desc"
    GetData();
    $("#descn").hide(); 
    $("#ascn").show();  
});
$("#asct").click(function(){
    window.$order = "GetData.asp?test=asc";
    GetData();
    $("#desct").show(); 
    $("#asct").hide();  
});
$("#desct").click(function(){
    window.$order = "GetData.asp?test=desc"
    GetData();
    $("#desct").hide(); 
    $("#asct").show();  
});
function GetData() {
    $.getJSON(window.$order, function(data){
    if (data[0].name == 'none') {
        $('#output').html("<div id='alert'>None Available</div>");
    } else {
        var len = data.length;
        html = '<table class="tbl small">'
        $time = 0
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {

            $time = (parseInt($time)+parseInt(data[i].time));
            if (data[i].overdue == "Yes") {
                html = html + '<tr style="background: #FF0000">'
            } else if (data[i].status == "RE ASSES") {
                html = html + '<tr style="background: #D0C0C0">'
            } else{
                html = html + '<tr>'
            }
            html = html + '<td class="border col1">'+data[i].line+'</td>'
            html = html + '<td class="border col2">'+data[i].no+'</td>'
            html = html + '<td class="border col3">'+data[i].desc+'</td>'           
            html = html + '<td class="border col4">'+data[i].loc+'</td>'            
            html = html + '<td class="border col5">'+data[i].time+'</td>'           
            html = html + '<td class="border col6">'+data[i].lastcal+'</td>'            
            html = html + '<td class="border col7">'+data[i].frequency+'</td>'          
            html = html + '<td class="border col8">'+data[i].status+'</td>' 
            if (data[i].external == "E" ) {
                html = html + '<td class="border col9">&#10004;</td>'   
            } else {
                html = html + '<td class="border col9"></td>'
            }
            html = html + '</tr>'           
            }
        html = html + '</table>'
        $('#output').html(html);
        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];
        var d = new Date();
        $('#tottime').html('Total time outstanding for ' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' : ' + $time);
    }
    });
}
```

My only concern is that I'm doing things the long way around, for example the #asc click functions for example - I'm not sure of a better way of achieving this without using a function for each of the click methods.

Also; inside the for loop, I've had to manually set the background colour with an if else as just trying to use .css('background','red') didn't work, but what I have here did.

Many thanks for your time and please feel free to point out any issues.

Comment: I wouldn't store the URL in `window.$order` but rather pass it as an argument to `GetData()`. By putting it in `window.$order` you're introducing state that `GetData()` relies on, which is bad and harder to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize the code by using HTML5 `data` property. For example,

```
 <a href="javascript:;" class="order-cls" data-order="asc" data-hide-property="descn" data-show-property="ascn">Link</a>
```

And in the js file

```
$(function(){
   $('a.order-cls').click(function(){
     var me = $(this),
         order = me.data('order'),
         hideprop = me.data('hideProperty'),
         showprop = me.data('showProperty');

      window.$order = "GetData.asp?no="+order;
      GetData();
      $("#"+showprop).show(); 
      $("#"+hideprop).hide();  
  });
});
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: Please don't imply that `data-` attributes are HTML 5 only. They work just fine on HTML 4 (just not part of the standard).

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, it appears I have quite a way to go!  I shall read through fully all the code here so I have a better understanding and I agree that using the html attributes will make life a lot easier.  It's all a good learning curve and like everything, we all have to start somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this, and that is already described by Sagar (use html5 data attributes).

This could all be done without ID selectors, while the URL should not be passed to GetData() through a global variable but through a parameter: `GetData(url);`

Anyhow, here is a shorter version of your code... Is it better... nah, unless you wrote it yourself it's pretty probably unreadable :D

```
var params = {
    "": 'order',
    "n": 'no',
    "t": 'test'
};

$('#asc, #desc, #ascn, #descn, #asct, #desct').on('click', function(event){
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.attr('id'),
        order = id.substr(0,1) == 'a' ? id.substr(0,3) : id.substr(0,4), // asc or desc
        type = id.substr(type=='asc'?3:4,1), // "", "t" or "n"
        param = params[type];
    window.$order = ['GetData.asp?',param,'=',order].join('');
    GetData();
    $('#desc' + type)[type=='asc'?'show':'hide']();
    $('#asc' + type)[type=='desc'?'show':'hide']();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need `.load()` method for it, because it waits for everything to be loaded first. Instead jQuery does have a method called `.ready()`, which just needs DOM *(Document Object Model)* to be ready, so you can make use of that and you can make use of refactoring it like this:

```
var myApp = myApp || {}; // use this to stop polluting the global scope
    myApp.GetData = function(){
       $.getJSON(myApp.$order, function(data){
           if (data[0].name == 'none') {
               $('#output').html("<div id='alert'>None Available</div>");
           } else {
              var len = data.length,
                 html = '<table class="tbl small">',
                $time = 0;
              for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
                  $time = (parseInt($time)+parseInt(data[i].time));
                  if (data[i].overdue == "Yes") {
                      html = html + '<tr style="background: #FF0000">'
                  } else if (data[i].status == "RE ASSES") {
                      html = html + '<tr style="background: #D0C0C0">'
                  } else{
                     html = html + '<tr>'
                  }
                 html = html + '<td class="border col1">'+data[i].line+'</td>'
                 html = html + '<td class="border col2">'+data[i].no+'</td>'
                 html = html + '<td class="border col3">'+data[i].desc+'</td>'           
                 html = html + '<td class="border col4">'+data[i].loc+'</td>'            
                html = html + '<td class="border col5">'+data[i].time+'</td>'           
                html = html + '<td class="border col6">'+data[i].lastcal+'</td>'            
                html = html + '<td class="border col7">'+data[i].frequency+'</td>'          
                html = html + '<td class="border col8">'+data[i].status+'</td>' 
                if (data[i].external == "E" ) {
                   html = html + '<td class="border col9">&#10004;</td>'   
                } else {
                   html = html + '<td class="border col9"></td>'
                }
                   html = html + '</tr>'           
               }
                  html = html + '</table>'
                  $('#output').html(html);
                  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                  var d = new Date();
                  $('#tottime').html('Total time outstanding for ' + 
                             monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' : ' + $time);
                }
        });
    };

$(function(){ //<----shorter way of writing $(document).ready(fn)
    // Note: you should bind your events like click, change etc in this block
    myApp.$order = "GetData.asp"; // now you can put in your custom var myApp
    myApp.GetData();
    myApp.$ord == '';
    $("#descn, #desc, #desct").hide(); // you can use this way to hide but 
                                       // better to hide with css like
                                       // #descn, #desc, #desct{display:none;}

    $("#asc, #desc, #ascn, #descn, #asct, #desct").click(function(){
        if(this.id === "asc"){
           myApp.$order = "GetData.asp?order=asc";
           $("#desc").show();  
           $("#asc").hide();
        }else if(this.id === "desc"){
           myApp.$order = "GetData.asp?order=desc";
           $("#desc").hide();  
           $("#asc").show();
        }else if(this.id === "ascn"){
           myApp.$order = "GetData.asp?no=asc";
           $("#descn").show(); 
           $("#ascn").hide();
        }else if(this.id === "descn"){
           myApp.$order = "GetData.asp?no=desc";
           $("#descn").hide(); 
           $("#ascn").show();
        }else if(this.id === "asct"){
           myApp.$order = "GetData.asp?test=asc";
           $("#desct").show(); 
           $("#asct").hide();
        }else if(this.id === "desct"){
           myApp.$order = "GetData.asp?test=desc";
           $("#desct").hide(); 
           $("#asct").show();
        }  

        myApp.GetData(); // <---you can call this function here now.

    });

});
```